# Instantiation of a template for local variable

Tags: c++

Is a template instantiated if a local automatic variable of that type is defined?

e.g.

```
template<typename T> class MyClass {
};

int main() {
  MyClass<int> var; // Does this cause instantiation?
}
```

Edit:

the reason why I'm asking this is the following code:

```
template<typename T> class get_false { public:
    static constexpr bool val = false; 
};

template<typename T>
class MyClass_2 {
  static_assert(get_false<T>::val, "Failure");
};

template<typename T, typename U = MyClass_2<T>>
class MyClass {};

int main() {
    MyClass<bool> obj; // I suppose this isn't instantiated
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think it might not be instantiated? Curious about your reasoning.

Comment: @Albert It is instantiated.

Comment: Added my reasoning. That will make the question a bit more verbose but I agree that might explain my doubts better.

Comment: I'm not sure that "test case" is quite correct, i believe the `typename U = MyClass_2<T>` is more akin to a pyedef/using statement which doesnt trigger an instation until it's used, which you don't do. I added a `U u;` member variable on my end and it fired.

Comment: That might be an answer with a bit of official documentation/references

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is instantiated.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class MyClass {
    public:

    MyClass() {
        std::cout << "instantiated" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass<int> var;
}
```

The program outputs "instantiated"  ⇒  the `MyClass` constructor is called  ⇒  the `var` object is instantiated.